# Cannot Find Duplicate Management in Lightning

Tags: duplicate-management, matcher

I am having difficulty managing matching rules in SF Lightning because I cannot get past step one of all the guides I have found. When I type "match" or "dup" into the quick find box, nothing comes up. Picture attached.

Have I just missed something obvious?

[image: "match"]

[image: "dup"]

Comment: What type of org are you working in?

Comment: Lightning Sales Cloud- Enterprise Edition

Comment: Assuming you're a system administrator, you should be able to see these setup items. You may need to contact technical support to have this feature enabled, as it is available in your edition. I don't know of any other situation where you wouldn't have this feature as long as you're in a supported edition.

Comment: Are you able to see the [potential duplicates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicates_existing_setup.htm&type=5) component in your lightning app builder?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The image attached is what I see in my org. I've added a link below to Salesforce's documentation on permission requirements for Duplicate Management. I would make sure that your profile (or associated permission sets) have both "Customize Application" and "View Setup and Configuration" enabled. You can find both of these under 'System Permissions.' If you still do not have visibility with both enabled, I would probably file a case with Salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Hello all! I contacted SF and it was an issue on their end. they are fixing it! Thank you for all the help!